# Bad statistical test results for LCG PRNG

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, random-seed

I created a simple LCG PRNG, using common constants in python.

```
class LcgPRNG():
    def __init__(self, mode):
        self.mode = mode
        self.startSeed = 1
        self.a = 25214903917
        self.e = 31
        self.m = 2**self.e
        self.c = 11
        self.periodCounter = 0
        self.startLcg()

    def startLcg(self):
        self.z = ((self.a * int(self.startSeed)) + self.c) % self.m
        return

    def lcg(self):
        self.z = ((self.a * int(self.z)) + self.c) % self.m
        return

    def next(self):
        # if(self.periodCounter >= 1000000):
        #     if(self.mode == 'changing'):
        #         self.startSeed = random.randint(0, 2**32)
        #     self.startLcg()
        #     self.periodCounter = 0
        self.lcg()
        # self.periodCounter += 1
        return int(self.z)
```

Note: I also tried to implement a custom period length so that i can have 2 different modes for the PRNG. One that always produces the same sequence(same startSeed) and one that changes the start seed every time. Just to explain the mess, but i wanted to show everything, to be safe. 
My Problem is, that it seems to be extremely weak when it comes to testing.
I use the dieharder testing suite for that. Also the PRNG isn't close to the speed
of build in PRNGs. Is that because i didn't wrap my lcg in the c dieharder library as recommended in the manpage(i don't want to do it that way) or is there a problem with my PRNG? 
Can you give me tips on how to improve the performance of my lcg, Is it possible that i piped my numbers wrong or did something else wrong, or does the performance problems simply lay in my lcg code? Any tips on how to improve the performance? 
I would like to at least pass 10 tests, I don't need a really good PRNG just something ok. 
And here are the test result and how i piped the numbers, just to show the whole process.
main:

```
    rng = LcgPRNG('changing')
    while True:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack('>I', rng.next()))
```

and i call dieharder like this:

```
python3 lcg.py | dieharder -g200 -a
```

and at last the results(at least a few of them but you get the point):
[DIEHARDER LCG RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI5r0.png) 
Those tests took 7.29 minutes to complete.
(Sidequestion: can someone tell me why diehard_runs and caps runs twice?)

If you have more question please ask them. 
Thanks for any Help you can provide :)

Comment: LCGs have well-known properties, some of which may be undesirable for pseudorandom number generation. (For instance, because it has a power-of-two modulus, your LCG produces values with weak low bits, so that, e.g., every other value is odd and every other value is even.)  See [Steele and Vigna](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf) for a review of many of the properties of LCGs.  In general, pseudorandom number generators with 32-bit seeds or other short seeds are far from appropriate for many situations, including scientific work or information security.

Comment: Your LCG could be slower than built-in ones just because it is in interpreted Python. Did you try to rewrite it in C for comparison ? BTW  why would you need to have constant a larger than the modulus ?

Comment: You are using the `c` and `a` that are typically used when `e==48`. Also, you should get better results if you make `e` 48 and have `next()` return only the high-order 32 bits, see [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Comment: *"isn't close to the speed of"* - How much slower is it?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the help. First of i know that LCGs aren't good PRNGs, but thats also not my goal. I changed my modulus as suggested by @PresidentJamesK.Polk and return only the higher-order 32 bits. Now the result are really good. So thanks for that hint, you can post your comment as an answer so that i can accept it if you want. Now my only Problem is the speed of the generator but for that i will try to look into it myself fist and after that, if i still need help, i will create another question. I think its better that way. Again thanks for the help :)

Comment: I'm still curious how much slower it is. (I made it a bit over twice as fast, but I don't know how far away it is from the "build in PRNGs" (unclear what that means exactly...))

Comment: @KellyBundy The dieharder module is what I'm using to test my PRNG with various statistical tests. But dieharder has already implemented PRNGs in its own code too. These are the PRNGs i mean by "build in PRNGs". Their communication with dieharder is just a lot faster, because they are already build in with the tests and don't need to communicate via the systems std. These PRNGs need only about a minute to complete the tests. My lcg needs 7-10. So there is a big difference. Did you mean you increased the speed of my lcg? If so can you tell me how, or which steps you took?

Comment: Ah, not a fair fight then :-). I sped up `rng.next()`, didn't write but just called it some large number of times (and put the results into a list, iirc). Used a generator with local variables for that, so no overhead for attribute lookup and extra function calls.